# Android: How to collect sensor data in background in Oreo?

Tags: android, background, android-sensors, android-8.0-oreo

I have an android app and I want to collect acclerometer data when app is in background. For OS versions < 8.0, I used background service to collect this data. But with Background Execution Limits imposed by Oreo, I am unable to do so.

I do not want to use foreground service to make OS think that my app is in foreground.

Hence, what is the correct way to implement this functionality in Oreo.

Thanks in advance.

Downvote should accompany with reason.

Comment: You shouldn't do this. If you are going to access sensor data in the background, the user should know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you can't. The best option is to use a foreground notification or a periodic job.

Comment: By periodic job do you mean use job scheduler?

Comment: yes, job scheduler. Not ideal for sensor but you haven't got other alternatives

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try.

Comment: @Kanika Did you manage to register the sensors, while the app in the background, using JobDispatcher with JobService?